# What is this? Is it harmful?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Anyone find out what this is? Looks like A Caterpillar with a home it made from surrounding items, this was found in VA in the moutians on our home.! It went back inside its home after attempting to touch it with my phone. It's the size of an adult female pinky.‍♀️[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be what is known as a [bagworm](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2011/09/14/bagworm-15/):
[image: bagworm image ©2004 Tony DiTerlizzi from: https://bugguide.net/node/view/8832]

According to the [University of Maryland extension Home & Garden Information Center](https://extension.umd.edu/hgic/topics/bagworms-trees-and-shrubs), they can cause significant damage to ornamental plants especially conifers.